# Return Object not a value - Slider VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, slider, vuejs3, loader

I wont to create my test slider in Vue3.
At last step i want to add loader for slowly internet connection.
If img is loading i want to add spinner.
I used Promise function, but i don't get a callback value.

I know in vue 3 is something like suspense but i want add function in my exercise.

In Browser i get this info:
**helpers.js?4da1:7 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error [object Object]
at HTMLImageElement.img.onerror**

```
<template>
  <div class="slides-wrapper">
    <button
    class="btn btn-primary btn-action btn-lg slides-prev"
    @click="changePhoto(-1)"
    :disabled="index === 0">
              <i class="icon icon-arrow-left"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="slides">
              <Slide
              :url="url"
              :text="numberSlides"/>
          </div>
          <button
          class="btn btn-primary btn-action btn-lg slides-next"
          @click="changePhoto(+1)"
          :disabled="index === lenghtTablePhoto -1">
              <i class="icon icon-arrow-right"></i>
          </button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { computed, ref } from 'vue';
import Slide from './Slide.vue';
import { prelodeImages } from '../helpers/helpers';

export default {
  name: 'SlideShow',
  components: {
    Slide,
  },
  props: {
    img: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
    },
  },

  setup(props) {
    const index = ref(0);
    const lenghtTablePhoto = ref(+props.img.length);
    const url = computed(() => props.img[index.value].url);
    const numberSlides = computed(() => `${index.value + 1}/${lenghtTablePhoto.value}`);
    function changePhoto(num) {
      if (props.img[index.value] !== undefined) {
        prelodeImages(url)
          .then((value) => {
            console.log(value);
            index.value += num;
          });
      }
    }

    return {
      index,
      lenghtTablePhoto,
      url,
      numberSlides,
      changePhoto,
      prelodeImages,
    };
  },

};

</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

.slides-wrapper {
        width: 500px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .slides-next,
    .slides-prev {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;

        transform: translateY(-50%);
    }

    .slides-prev {
        left: 0;
    }

    .slides-next {
        right: 0;
    }

</style>
```

and here is my function:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line import/prefer-default-export
export function prelodeImages(url) {
  const img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = url;
  const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    img.onload = () => resolve(url);
    img.onerror = () => reject(new Error(`Error ${url}`));
  });

  return p;
}
```

Comment: prelodeImages(url.value)

Comment: It's not works ;(